# Subdomain always redirect to WWW (home page)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want, when open subdomain to return existing Wordpress page ex. www.example.com/custom-wordpress-page.

Server OS is CentOS 6.6, while Web Server (httpd) is Apache 2.2.15.

It have installed and configured Wordpress with .htaccess files configured for it's mod_rewrite.

Root folder is /var/www/html.

.htaccess file is in /var/www/html/.htaccess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This configuration is working very well with one domain (ex. example.com). Today I wanted to add subdomain (ex. subdomain.example.com).

I tried multiple solutions including VirtualHosts with/without NameVirtualHost in httpd.conf file, also adding RewrriteCond&RewriteRule 
under mod_rewrite in .htaccess file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email-address-redacted
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email-address-redacted
        ServerName subdomain.example.com
        ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
        Redirect permanent / http://example.com/custom-wordpress-page
</VirtualHost>
```

Also in first VirtualHost, I tried *.example.com instead off www.example.com.
In second one, I tried to make Reverse Proxy using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse.

Instead of using :*80 I tried using IP address of server and domain name.

Using .htaccess Rewrite rule with/without VirtualHosts gave no results.

subdomain.example.com always opens www.example.com instead of www.example.com/custom-wordpress-page.

Keep in mind - there is a lot of threads like this, but I tried many of them, including many tutorials but they aren't working alongside Wordpress.

Edit : Want to add that there are no wildcards in DNS records. There are NS records, one A record for example.com, one A record for subdomain.example.com and CNAME record for www that is poiting to example.com. There are NO *.

Comment: Do you have a Wordpress installation at `/var/www/html/custom-wordpress-page` or some other content at `.../custom-wordpress-page`?

Comment: No, it's not Wordpress installation, it is Permalink of WordPress Page.

Comment: So you want the subdomain point to some permalink of your Wordpress installation?

Comment: Yes, if possible of course

Comment: And if you call http://example.com/custom-wordpress-page manually, the correct page shows? Or does it also show the home page?

Comment: Yes it does, it shows correct page

Comment: Strange, from what you've shown, I would guess there are additional rules or directives, because `Redirect` looks ok.

Comment: Do you have idea, where could I look for it? I'm desperate with jt...

Comment: Just the usual, server config, .htaccess, and Apache access and error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with hosting provider DNS records, configuration was correct, but I had to call provider to check records in their system and fix what is broken. After they done their job, it works correctly.